# What's more accepted: "I know that" vs "I know this" & "I know it"?

Tags: style

What's more accepted in the spoken English:

> 1) "I know **that**"
>   2) "I know **this**"
>   3) "I know **it**"?

Context:

> 1) Q. "Do you know Oxford university?" A. "Yes, I know **it / this / that**"
>
> 2) Q. "There are so many people here"? A. "Yes, I know **it / this / that**"

I'd like to get examples for using "I know this" or "I know that"

Answer (score 3):

None of those are an idiom, the phrases do not mean anything more than what the words literally say.

If you don't know which pronoun to choose, Google provides some good definitions to help:

> To know that

- used to identify a specific person or thing observed by the speaker.
- referring to the more distant of two things near to the speaker (the other, if specified, being identified by “this”).
- referring to a specific thing previously mentioned (NOT *just* mentioned), known, or understood.
- used in singling out someone or something and ascribing a distinctive feature to them.
- used to introduce a defining or restrictive clause, especially one essential to identification (Use *that* if a clause follows, i.e. *To know that he was still out there was shocking.*)

> To know this

- used to identify a specific person or thing close at hand or being indicated or experienced.
- referring to the nearer of two things close to the speaker (the other, if specified, being identified by “that”).
- referring to a specific thing or situation just mentioned.

> To know it

*It* is a general neuter, non-personal pronoun in English that doesn't relate to things previously mentioned in earlier context or conversation like *this* or *that*.  If no earlier context or conversation exists, *it* would be used.

So the right pronoun depends on what you are knowing and how it relates to previous conversation or context.